# SQL Server re-calculate or not?

Tags: sql-server

There is an expression which I've build to reduce the time section out of date time and to ZERO it.

```
 DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, PayDate), 0)
```

My question is in this query (pseudo code) :

```
select 
    DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, PayDate), 0), 
    DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, PayDate), 0) + 3
where DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, PayDate), 0) > 3
```

The `DateAdd` expressions are all the same.

Here is my question :

- Does SQL Server **re-calculate** each time it sees this expression (in the `select` and in the `where` clause...)

Comment: I can't claim to fully understand your question, but why not try it and see?

Comment: i meant that : Does the sql recalculates this expression each time : DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, PayDate), 0) ?????

Comment: @Mid787: Do you mean to ask whether SQL Server re-calculates every occurrence of DATEADD in your query even if they are all identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a function several times in a query, it will be called every time it is used.

The fact that you call it with the same parameters make no difference.

So yes, `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` will be called three times each.

Comment: Even a deterministic function called with the same parameters? Seems like the optimiser might be missing a trick there, then?

Comment: i meant that  : Does the sql recalculates this expression each time : DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, PayDate), 0)  ?????

Comment: @Mid787: I believe, this answer means to reply a definitive *yes* to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use:

```
SELECT pd, pd+3
FROM
  ( SELECT DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, PayDate), 0) AS pd
    FROM ...
  )
WHERE pd > 3
```

The code looks more elegant and you can check performance comparing to your previous code.

---

You can also check this (half-improving):

```
SELECT pd, pd+3
FROM
  ( SELECT DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, PayDate), 0) AS pd
    FROM ...
    WHERE DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, PayDate), 0) > 3
  )
```

Testing with a big table will show some evidence.

Comment: still  , didnt get answer to my specific question : Does "DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, PayDate), 0)" will be calculated each time ?

Comment: @Mid787: I agree with you that this doesn't answer your specific question, but it seems like you are interested that DATEADD be *not* recalculated, and this answer at least shows how to hint SQL Server strongly about the way you'd like it to be.

Comment: @Andriy: thnx. (to Mid787: What I should have added is that I don't know the details of SQL-Server optimizer and I can't test now, but testing different versions with a big table (and counting the times needed) will give you enough evidence to conclude what happens in the inside of the optimizer.)