# In T-SQL, can an expression be re-used in a query without re-calculating the expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

For example, I want to do this:

```
SELECT (A AND (B OR C)) AS ExpressionOne,
       NOT (A AND (B OR C)) AS NotExpressionOne
FROM SomeTable
```

Where A, B, and C can be any expression.

Is there some mechanism in SQL Server to do this without calculating (A AND (B OR C)) multiple times for each row of the SELECT?

The question [SQL Server re-calculate or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144885/sql-server-re-calculate-or-not) notes that the value will be re-calculated, and gives one possible solution (a sub-query), but doesn't mention if that is the only possible solution.

Comment: Often that can be optimized, so it won't be recalculated every time. However, you can use a common-table-expression or a sub-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do it with a common table expression (CTE) like this:

```
WITH (Expression (One, otherColumns) as 
    (SELECT (A AND (B OR C)), othercolumns FROM SomeTable)
SELECT One, NOT One, othercolumns
FROM Expression
```

But it isn't at all clear that this is any more efficient than SQLServer's optimizations -- especially for different calculations on the same columns, I'd expect it to be pretty efficient already. In particular, a CTE has to save the result of the calculation somewhere, either in memory or on disk if it's too big. It pays to try it out and see whether it's faster to do the calculation twice or create the in-memory structure but calculate only once.

Comment: I prefer readability even if SQL-Server would optimize it (what's [not so clear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301058/does-sql-server-optimize-dateadd-calculation-in-select-query)). So instead of repeating all the complex stuff which could change next wwek anyway, i prefer to encapsulate it in a CTE.

Comment: Not clear to me that it is more readable or saves much duplication here. If it's a query that'll be used over and over again, worth it to run some performance tests.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer  [common-table-expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) because they are  easy to read and to maintain.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT (A AND (B OR C)) AS ExpressionOne,
       NOT (A AND (B OR C)) AS NotExpressionOne,
       OtherColumns
    FROM SomeTable
)
SELECT ExpressionOne, NotExpressionOne, ...
FROM CTE
```

You could also use a [sub-query](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx).